# Hierarchical data to array / json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to learn how to properly encode the results of a MySQL query as an array/JSON.  I can do the basics, what I'm have difficulty with is getting a specific structure.

My data looks like this:

```
db_name   file_type  name   value   count
archive   A          send   vid     338
archive   A          perm   trrr    323
archive   A          mod    2016    339
archive   B          rate   32K     5414
archive   B          off    Bleep   466
archive   B          level  1222    466
```

I would like to create an array that I can encode as JSON, looking like this:

```
{
 "archive": {
    "A": {
      "send": {
        "vid": 338
        }
      "perm": {
        "trrr": 323
        }
      "mod": {
        "2016": 339
        },
    "B": {
      "rate": {
        "32K": 5414
        }
      "off": {
        "Bleep": 466
        }
      "level": {
        "1222": 466
        }
   }
}
```

Any help or push in the right direction is appreciated.  Thank you!

**EDIT 2:**  Based on Farzad's answer.  Getting close.  I am trying to group on db_name, file_type, and name.  Ideally this would be done in a way that results in no square brackets in my JSON output.  In progress:

```
$result = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
};

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                    $outp[$row["file_type"]][] = array(
                                $row["name"] => array($row["value"] => $row["count"])
                            );
                }

$result = array('archive' => $outp); 
echo json_encode($result);
```

**EDIT 3**  This did the trick:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                    $outp[$row["file_type"]][$row["name"]][] = array(
                                array($row["value"]=> $row["counts"])
                            );
                }

$result = array('original' => $outp);  

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: @Phoebe. I don't need you to accept my answer as solution but you have had not any code at the beginning and so i edited your question to reference my answer since you had not any code! That is the basic of programming! honor code!  check your edit history !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this :

Edit : I see you do some kind of group by too, add [] too! it will work, however, you need to put all "A" data in list

```
while ($result->fetch()) {
                        $outp[$file_type][] = array(
                                    $name => array($value=> $count)
                                );


                    }
$result = array('archive' => $outp);
echo json_encode($result);
```

this is a test

```
$file_type = 'type';
$name = 'name';
$count = 'cont';
$value = 'value';
$outp= array();
                        $outp[$file_type][] = array(
                                    $name => array($value=> $count)
                                );



echo json_encode($outp);
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.  But, when I try your approach (not the second, self-contained "test" one) I get errors because it's looking for $count and others as a variable, not as members of the array that's returned from my query.  I'll add more code to my original question now.

Comment: Actually, my error is "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on resource"

Comment: Never mind, getting closer now.  I'll post my solution once I get it, but for now, I'll update code-in-progress, above.

Comment: I just saw your comment, Phoebe , my code is based on the mysql prepared statement, and you use mysql_query which i don't recommend it  to you since it's not secure.  I see u have edited your question based on my answer, does it have a problem !?

Comment: And I recommend to not change the code in Question for future reference. I mean, Since people may have your original question and if you edit the original code with answers the question also would be an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Farzad. I will append code next time instead of editing it.  Unfortunately, I didn't see this suggestion until I edited the code (again).  Trying to group on three variables, with no square brackets in the resulting JSON.

Comment: @Phoebe , you didn't have any code, your first code is my code! just changing vars!  anyway , you need to put them in square bracket because you may have multiple record with same file_type based on your sample